# How can I create a jQuery alert box?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

How can I create a jQuery alert box that has a Yes/No button? I would also like to store the value from the clicked button on the alert box.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's a little difficult to understand exactly what you're trying to accomplish, so in order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you're trying to say, you can have a confirmation that pops up when a button is clicked on your page:

```
<input type="button" id="myYES" value="YES" onclick="doStuff();" />
```

Then in your JavaScript you'll have your onclick handler:

```
function doStuff(){
    if(confirm('Do you wish to save the events?')) {
        // your code logic here if true ("ok" is clicked in most cases)
    } else {
        // your other logic here if false ("cancel" is clicked in most cases)
    }  
}
```

You will have to be more clear in your description for a more concrete answer.

Answer (score -1):

jQuery doesn't have an alert. JavaScript is the one that can show alerts, but the one you are looking for is the `confirm()` JavaScript function. You can store the value of the `confirm()` function to a variable and check the result.

Check this out for and example: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/confirm.htm

However, I recommend you to use bootbox. It is simple and easy to use, and is more "pretty": 
http://bootboxjs.com/

Comment: Thanks for reply, Could you suggest how to call client side btn_click event method in client side funthion when click yes bttoun?

Comment: well you if you want to call a click event in the client side you can trigger the click of the button that you want to call with jquery like this $("#btnclick").trigger("click", ""); call this trigger if the callback of the bootbox is true or if the confirm is true